# asp.net mvc bootstrap tab add javascript including partialview automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

First of all i want to add purchase and sales in same view.And there will be many to one sales or many to one purchases. So i need to call sales model several times in one view with partial view. Then i encountered such a problem.

I have problem with MVC bootstrap tabs. I have one bootstrap tab. In first tab call partialview static like

```
 @Html.Partial("_PurchaseDeal")
```

But then i add new tabs with add tab button. It is normally adds tabs and load partialview with this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(".purchase").on("click", "a", function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               if (!$(this).hasClass('add-purchase')) { debugger
                   $(this).tab('show');
               }
           })
                .on("click", "span", function () {
                                   $(this).parent().remove();
                    $(".purchase li").children('a').first().click();
                });



                       $('.add-purchase').click(function (e) {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           var id = $(".purchase").children().length; //think about it ;)
                           var tabId = 'purchase_' + id;
                           debugger
                           $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#purchase_' + id + '">P-'+id+'</a> <span> x </span></li>');

                           $('.purchasetab').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">' + '</div>');
                           debugger

                           $.ajax({
                               url: '@Url.Action("ReturnPurchasePartial", "DEALs")',
                               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                               type: 'GET',
                               dataType: 'html',
                               success: function (data) {
                                   debugger
                                   $('#'+tabId).html(data);
                               },
                               error:function()
                               {
                                   alert('Could not save the deal');
                               }

                           });

                           $('.purchase li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
                           debugger
                       });

</script>
```

Now my problem is in first time when i call partial view as a static version javascripts in partialview fires normally.
But when i call partialview inside a javascript code dynamically javascripts in the same partial view are not firing.

Please could anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: It's tricky to know what your asking but I think basically you need to call function to respect the tabs after the html has been loaded

Comment: Scripts are loading with partialview but not firing. Which function do you mean i need to call after html has been loaded?

Comment: Any functions that have something todo with the html you have just loaded.  If you are loading in javascript with your partial view then  are you loading the same javascript twice or more times, this feels like it'll cause problems in the browser. I wouldn't have the javascript in the partial view myself and that might solve your problem. It's tricky to understand your issue.

Comment: Ok thank you @RichardHousham I clear javascripts inside the called partialview. My issue is not so complicated. I add dynamic tabs and call same partialview many times from those addedd dynamic tabs.